# Parameter to a URL preventing javascript from working properly?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

First of all, my whole web site works fine. All the pages, up to now, have no URL parameter. Now the problem begins. I have a flash banner that has to be a PNG static image on Apple mobile devices. It works great until I create a page with a parameter (ex: mysite.com/Controller1/Page1/1). As soon as I have a parameter, both banners (flash and PNG) appear.

Here's my iOS.js:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))
{
    alert("This was called - Mac mobile devices");
    document.write('<style type="text/css"><!--#swf{display:none;}--></style>');
}
else {
    alert("This was called - PC");
    document.write('<style type="text/css"><!--#no-swf{display:none;}--></style><script src="js/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
}
```

Here's the summary of my partial view Header (just extracted from _Layout where the behavior was the same):

```
@Html.JsScript("../../Scripts/iOS.js")

<div id="swf">
    MY FLASH BANNER
</div>
<div id="no-swf">
    MY STATIC IMAGE
</div>
```

When I try a normal page (no parameter), I always have the message box `This was called - PC` but when I add a parameter (even on the same page!), I don't get any message.

Maybe it is a routing problem? I simplified to the maximum to leave only one route:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
        null, // Nom d'itinéraire
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL avec des paramètres
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Paramètres par défaut
    );
```

Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: Typically "parameter" in the context of a URL refers to something in the query as in `/path?param-name=param-value`.  What do you mean by parameter in "mysite.com/Controller1/Page1/1"?

Comment: mysite.com/Controller1/Page1/1 is equal to mysite.com/Controller1/Page1//path?id=1. It's only cleaner. Of course it needs to be set.

Comment: So "mysite.com/Controller1/Page1" works but "mysite.com/Controller1/Page1/1" does not?

Comment: The page works, only the javascript isn't called so the flash and the static banner are shown one on top of the other (and because the flash one is transparent, it's ugly)

Comment: Is iOS.js loaded via a relative URL?  When you add a path element, you need to add a `../` to a relative URL to get it to refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> @Html.JsScript("../../Scripts/iOS.js")
> ```

When you add an element to the path, you need to add a `../` to your relative URLs or use a `<base href="...">` to make sure the relative URLs resolve to the same absolute URL.

Maybe the above should become

> ```
> @Html.JsScript("../../../Scripts/iOS.js")
> ```

or you can add

```
<base href="http://mysite.com/Controller1/Page1/">
```

near the top of your page.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4 says

> In HTML, links and references to external images, applets, form-processing programs, style sheets, etc. are always specified by a URI. Relative URIs are resolved according to a base URI, which may come from a variety of sources. The BASE element allows authors to specify a document's base URI explicitly.
>
> When present, the BASE element must appear in the HEAD section of an HTML document, before any element that refers to an external source. The path information specified by the BASE element only affects URIs in the document where the element appears.